# Javascript to jquery multiple textarea size

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

i found a solution for a problem i have in here http://jsfiddle.net/2UDdh/43/light but i am trying to adapt it for jquery because i would like to later use .each() and "this" because i have multiple textarea coming from db with diferent id's.

```
    var textContainer, textareaSize, input;
var autoSize = function() {
  textareaSize.innerHTML = input.value + '\n';
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  textContainer = document.querySelector('.textarea-container');
  textareaSize = textContainer.querySelector('.textarea-size');
  input = textContainer.querySelector('textarea');

  autoSize();
  input.addEventListener('input', autoSize);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly which part you're having trouble with?  Including jquery? doc.ready?  basic class selector?  adding an event listener?   removing the terrible global variables?  Or did you just want someone to do it for you?

Comment: Why introduce jQuery at all? Modern web browsers have, *shocker*, "evolved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use jQuery, you could create a jQuery plugin.

You are essentially adding line-feed characters to an invisible `<div>` to control the size of the wrapped `<textarea>`.

```js
/* jquery.textarea-resizer.js */
(function($) {
  var autoSize = function(input, textareaSize) {
    $(textareaSize).html($(input).val() + '\n');
  };
  var initResizer = function(target) {
    if (!$(target).data('resizer-active')) {
      var textareaSize = $(target).find('.textarea-size');
      var input = $(target).find('textarea');
      autoSize(input, textareaSize);
      $(input).on('input', function(e) {
        autoSize(e.target, textareaSize);
      });
      $(target).data('resizer-active', true); // Initialize only once
    }
  }
  $.fn.textareaResizer = function() {
    this.each(function() {
      initResizer(this);
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

$('.textarea-container').textareaResizer(); // Initialize all 3 at once!
```

```css
.textarea-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.textarea-container textarea,
.textarea-container .textarea-size {
  min-height: 25px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.textarea-container textarea {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  resize: none;
  white-space: normal;
}

.textarea-container .textarea-size {
  visibility: hidden;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="textarea-container">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="textarea-size"></div>
</div>

<div class="textarea-container">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="textarea-size"></div>
</div>

<div class="textarea-container">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="textarea-size"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are looking for this. but I may suggest try it by yourself for a better understanding.

```js
var textContainer, textareaSize, input;

var autoSize = function () {
  textareaSize.html(input.val() + '\n') ;
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    textContainer = $('.textarea-container');
  textareaSize = $('.textarea-size');
  input = $('textarea');
  autoSize();
  input.on('input',autoSize);

})
```

```css
.textarea-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

textarea, .textarea-size {
  min-height: 25px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

textarea {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  resize:none;
  white-space: normal;
}

.textarea-size {
  visibility: hidden;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textarea-container">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="textarea-size"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't see how this allows OP to use it on multiple textarea